# Typescript: mark an object property as non-enumerable?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm using nominal typing/branding to represent values that passed through React's useMemo.

```
type Memoed<T> = T extends Primitive ? T
  : T extends { __MEMOED: true } ? T
  : T & { __MEMOED: true };

declare function useMemo<T extends any>(
  callback: () => T,
  deps: ReadonlyArray<Primitive | Memoed<object>>,
): Memoed<T>;
```

This works fine most of the time. However, this causes issues when I'm using `Object.keys`, `Object.values`, or when I'm spreading objects. E.g. if I spread a memoized object to create a new object, the new object isn't memoized. However, it would still have the `__IS_USE_MEMO` property, so Typescript would allow it as an argument to `useMemo`. E.g.:

```
const objA = useMemo(() => ({ a: 1 }), []);
const objB = { ...objA };
const objC = useMemo(() => objB, [objB]); // Should be error
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgSwLYOAgbtAvFAzsRAOwHMoAfKQgVyQCMI5ypaB7FgGwgENCnr32TKoQAmEAGYJCEEQG4AUPNCQoAWQhIWMgDwAVAHxQcuqBAAewCKNyxEKNJigB%20KLvlQPUAFyvTFqyI2AN5QAPqhAJIAyqEAqlEAoqGqCaoA8j4EVNAAvs6u7p4%20JgBkUCHh0XGJyakZUFm5CvJiAMbsXHDQ4sKtaCy8VLgQ6pp6fpbWUDwg%20gAUhR6tXAK0XK0A1j5zAJRGhroANItQYmC4PgBK3CID7CAAgnBwXCDao1oi2iy0AFYQfX0%20mOOx8Hx0BmarQG%20CgP1%20DyMUCGIw0LDmu32UDmIS4PgAjFAcjtDlAANoAXR2CmhhFh8IAQkiQgA6NnwxE5Gkw4Bwv4AYSRKI%20GL2WEMjNJZMZVIUQA)

If I can mark `__MEMOED` has non-enumerable, then this problem should go away. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the only way to do this would be to define a class with your "memoed" mark as a method (doesn't technically need to be a method, but extending a prototype with anything else is more complicated).

This seems to actually work (instead of your definition for `__MEMOED`):

```
declare class __MEMOED {
  memoed(): true
}

type Memoed<T> = T extends Primitive ? T
  : T extends __MEMOED ? T
  : T & __MEMOED
```

Although… if you memo anything that's not a basic Object, things get really weird and at that point you really need to extend the base class.

Comment: This doesn't seem to produce an error: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgSwLYOAgbtAvFAzsRAOwHMoAfKQgVyQCMI5ypaB7FgGwgENCnr32TKoQAmEAGYJCEEQG4AUPIDGLQvigB9DQFkAotoDyugCJQcAZRB0OACgDkWvYZN2AlAvmhIUbRCQsZAB4AFQA+MyhgqAgAD2AIUVxYRBQ0TCgAfkj5KCgALkjouISRJIBvKABtR30jYwBdAoIqaABfTOzcgqiAMigK6p1ak0aoZraPMSV2LjhocWElNFUoKlwIX38QovjEqB4QUJscqCUuAVouJQBrAptXM3DggBoTsTBcAoAlbhFVdhAAEE4HAuCBAvBkKgMNAKJsAiJAixaAArCBLUKhV6uArwoJhDwqNTAKDIlGAiJrDZ+Fg2e6PKA2CpcAoARigrVczyq9XcylU6jJACEIhUAHQSskU1oKImC1EAYUp63hdIeWHCwu5lWFvNkUAA9AaoOYABYsKjsETMaAMOAsODyIA

Comment: I was wrong about the issue, Symbols are enumerable, it's just we almost never have them as own properties of objects. So, back to classes for good.

Comment: I was afraid you'd have to extend the base "memoed" class all the time but it's actually quite simple. Edited my answer.

Comment: That's really useful!